# Is this proper usage of await async stuff?

Tags: async-await

I've got these two lines of code:

```
var tasks = orders.Select(order => Task.Run(() => svc.Register(order)));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

And then the relevant part of the Register method looks like this:

```
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("/api/external/client", content);
if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var orderAccepted = string.IsNullOrEmpty(response);
}
```

This is in a console application, so my thinking is that this will do all the posts at the same time, and then to avoid having the console application end before the posts are complete I assume I would need to WaitAll.

Not 100% sure if this works the way I think though, and even if it does I also wonder if it's cool to set up all the Tasks with the Select() method the way I did or if that seems like a strange way to do it.

EDIT:

Also, after some thought I wonder is this a better way:

```
Parallel.ForEach(orders, async order => { await svc.Register(order); });
```

Comment: What is the signature of your Register method?

Comment: @pere57 public async Task Register(Order order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are Using `Task.Run` if you're already invoking an asynchronous method?

Using LINQ to build the task list is perfectly valid. In fact, if you use `Task.WhenAll`, you can just do this:

```
Task.WhenAll(orders.Select(order => svc.Register(order))).Wait();
```

OR, if you are using the C# 7.1 or above, you can take advantage of [async Main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main):

```
await Task.WhenAll(orders.Select(order => svc.Register(order)));
```

`Parallel.ForEach` is more suitable for CPU intensive workloads and not I/O intensive workloads like this.

In any case, you'll be limited by the [service point manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager)'s default connection limit.

Comment: Using .Wait() will block, and cancel out any benefits of using async / await.

Comment: @Peregrine It's a console application and it was already using `WaitAll`.

Comment: @Peregrine I have to wait or if the console application completes before the threads are completed (which it will) then it will kill them and they won't finish. But this at least allows them all to process concurrently.

Comment: @BVernon Take a look at Stepehn Cleary's Nito.AsyncEx library - especially the AsyncContext class for how to do async console applications properly. More details at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html

Comment: @Peregrine Cool, thanks for that link. In this case it's a command line console app that does a number of other jobs, none of which are asynchronous. So I think Pauolo's answer will be the path of least resistance for now, but I agree I will definitely setup up any new console apps that need to do asynchronous stuff that way in the future.

Comment: @PauloMorgado To answer your question... I have no idea. I think originally I used `Task.Run` because the Register method wasn't async. But then I was like "oh, I should make Register async" and neglected to realize I no longer needed `Task.Run`. In any case, thanks for your answer. Works great!